# Define Multiple-Columns as PK in YDN-DB

Tags: ydn-db

When define a schema with ydn-db I can define a single column as PK with this code:

```
var products = {
    name: 'products',
    keyPath: 'id_product',
    autoIncrement: true,
    indexes: [
        {keyPath: 'id_product'},
        {keyPath: 'id_supplier'}
    ]
};

var schema = {
    stores: [products]
};
```

How I can define a Store (table) with one PK with two columns or more? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can define a Store (table) with one PK with two columns or more?

I am not sure answering your question. IndexedDB (ynd-db is very IDB centric) can have only one PK. But primary key can be compound key compose of multiple keyPath (column) using [array keypath](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-valid-key-path). It is define like this

```
var products = {
  name: 'products',
  keyPath: ['id_category', id_product']
};
```